# A question about CE marking

Tags: emc, ce

If an electrical enclosure is interfaced with CE marked devices, does it still require assessments before using CE marking on it?

So if one makes an enclosure using a CE marked PSU and other CE marked electronic units; would that still require tests as a system to be verified as CE?

Comment: Remember this rule: CE + CE != CE.

Answer (score 3):

An enclosure that contains 1 or more CE marked electrical items may still not meet the required standards such as EMC and the low voltage directive. You have to do an assessment of the finished article (enclosure and bits inside) and CE mark the whole thing if you are selling "the whole thing" in the EU.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reference I could verify this or infer this from the rules? (the whole thing requiring tests even though the enclosure is composed of CE marked components)

Comment: @user1245 you should really look that up yourself.  ‘Some dude on the internet said it was ok’ is not a defence.

Comment: It may not require extensive testing if you are to self-certify. What rules are you reading?

Comment: [This web page](https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/ce-marking_en) is the turn-to place that I have used before. Read the "Blue Guide" to begin with.

Comment: There used to be some nice flow diagrams on that site but I can't seem to find them anymore unfortunately.

Comment: [The new approach guide](https://op.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/4f6721ee-8008-4fd7-acf7-9d03448d49e5) - it's a 300 Meg pdf so be warned.

Comment: Or just read the relevant directives, they are just some 50 pages per directive or so, instead of a whole tome. Basically: does it contain electronics, yes/no? If yes then RoHS and WEEE apply. Does it contain anything wireless yes/no? If yes then RED and LVD directives apply. Otherwise, does it have a supply >50VAC or >75VDC? If so then LVD applies. If doesn't contain anything wireless but contains other things affected by EMC, then the EMC directive applies.

Comment: An old but expert guide to the regulations at the time: https://www.emcstandards.co.uk/ce-ce-does-not-equal-ce

Comment: Also, think about the machinery directive. Imagine you have a CE marked (but) weak motor shaft that couldn't cause a significant nip hazard. Then you decided to use two of them to produce more shaft power...

Comment: @Andyaka Just a practical question. If an electronic enclosure output(say it outputs DC voltage or wavelength) claims an output with an uncertainty in your product manual and you test it with your own measurement  equipment in lab. Would you perform that measurement with a calibrated measurement equipment as  a part of CE?

Comment: You must use calibrated equipment but this is not really to do with CE unless the voltage was close to exceeding that required by the LVD.

Answer (score 2):

You need to CE mark the end product put on the market, no matter if it contains CE marked components or not.

If that means a new 3rd party EMC test or just self-certification depends on what the product does. You may be able to reason about it and document that you haven't added anything that should affect how the individual components were previously tested. Or you may need to do additional testing.

For example, if you put a product with an antenna inside an enclosure, you cannot reasonably state that you haven't done anything affecting radio compliance.

There's also the whole WEEEE circus where the end product needs WEEE marking and dealing with electronics recycling, but that's a big chapter of its own.

Comment: Thanks; I also need to be sure about it. Is there any reference I could verify this or infer this from the rules? (the whole thing requiring tests even though the enclosure is composed of CE marked components)

Comment: "You need to CE mark the end product put on the market, no matter if it contains CE marked components or not." Where can I find this or infer this from the official code?

Comment: @user1245 References will be the specific EU directives: EMC, LVD, RED, RoHS and so on. If you know which ones that apply to your product, I might be able to dig up the relevant source for you.